# terminal error : setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, terminal

this code for classification

```
# Load data
adj, features, y_train, y_val, labels, y_test, train_mask, val_mask, test_mask = 
load_data(FLAGS.dataset)
#labels=load_data(FLAGS.dataset)
# Some preprocessing
XX=features
yy=labels
selectedfeatures= SelectKBest(chi2, k=200).fit_transform(XX,yy)
selectedfeatures = preprocess_features(selectedfeatures)
Define placeholders
placeholders = {
'support': [tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32) for _ in range(num_supports)],
'selectedfeatures': tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=tf.constant(selectedfeatures[2], dtype=tf.int64)),
'labels': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, y_train.shape[1])),
'labels_mask': tf.placeholder(tf.int32),
'dropout': tf.placeholder_with_default(0., shape=()),
'num_features_nonzero': tf.placeholder(tf.int32)  # helper variable for sparse dropout
}
# Create model
model = model_func(placeholders, input_dim=selectedfeatures[2][1], logging=True)
# Initialize session
sess = tf.Session()
# Define model evaluation function
def evaluate(selectedfeatures, support, labels, mask, placeholders):
t_test = time.time()
feed_dict_val = construct_feed_dict(selectedfeatures, support, labels, mask, placeholders)
outs_val = sess.run([model.loss, model.accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict_val)
return outs_val[0], outs_val[1], (time.time() - t_test)
# Init variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
cost_val = []
# Train model
for epoch in range(FLAGS.epochs):

t = time.time()
# Construct feed dictionary
feed_dict = construct_feed_dict(features, support, y_train, train_mask, placeholders)
feed_dict.update({placeholders['dropout']: FLAGS.dropout})

# Training step
outs = sess.run([model.opt_op, model.loss, model.accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)

# Validation
cost, acc, duration = evaluate(features, support, y_val, val_mask, placeholders)
cost_val.append(cost)

# Print results
print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "train_loss=", "{:.5f}".format(outs[1]),
      "train_acc=", "{:.5f}".format(outs[2]), "val_loss=", "{:.5f}".format(cost),
      "val_acc=", "{:.5f}".format(acc), "time=", "{:.5f}".format(time.time() - t))
print("Optimization Finished!")

# Testing
test_cost, test_acc, test_duration = evaluate(features, support, y_test, test_mask, placeholders)
print("Test set results:", "cost=", "{:.5f}".format(test_cost),
  "accuracy=", "{:.5f}".format(test_acc), "time=", "{:.5f}".format(test_duration))
```

. when i tried to execute in terminal, i got the following error

File "train.py", line 91, in 
outs = sess.run([model.opt_op, model.loss, model.accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: did u try using ```list(...)``` around the array when u inputted it to ```feed_dict```

Comment: above code is running without any problem on spider but on terminal appear above error why?